# How does matchmaking in Gwent's Arena Mode work?

Tags: gwent

I noticed that matches become harder after I have 3-4 wins in Arena Mode. Is it because I face only opponents who has same number of wins? Or maybe it's somehow affected by my regular MMR?

I cannot find any explanation in my PS4 version, mb PC version have anything about it. I've also checked original  [Arena mode announcement](https://www.playgwent.com/en/news/16221/enter-the-arena-gwents-new-game-mode) but found nothing about matchmaking there.

So how does matchmaking work in Arena?